# Subscription to behaviour subject not returning new values

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a session details endpoint which I want to hit when my application starts, and after fetching any such details, I want to emit some values using behavior subjects that the rest of my application components can retrieve when needed.

I have created a session details service as follows:

```
export class SessionDetailsService {

  public currentUser: BehaviorSubject<IUser> = new BehaviorSubject<IUser>(undefined);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getSession = () => {
    return this.http.get<ISessionDetails>('http://localhost:8080/services/sessiondetails').subscribe((sessionDetails) => {
        this.currentUser.next(sessionDetails.user ? sessionDetails.user : undefined);
      });
  }
}
```

In my root app component `ngOnit` I am calling my `getSession` method in the above service.

This indeed triggers the HTTP request, but I am finding when a certain component loads that are subscribing to the `currentUser` behavior subject it is always returning an undefined value, even though I can see through debugging that there is a user property present on the sessionDetails response parameter in my HTTP get subscription callback, so I would expect a call to `this.currentUser.next(sessionDetails.user)` to have been made so my components interested in this value would get the full user value.

In my other components that are interested in this user value, I am subscribing in the ngOnit as follows:

```
this.sessionDetailsService.currentUser.subscribe((currentUser) => {
      this.userPresent = currentUser !== undefined;
    });
```

It's just setting a flag as you can tell, but is always set to false as the value coming through is still undefined.

I feel like I am misunderstanding something fundamental here.

Can anyone assist and explain where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have several instances of this service, most probably because you provided it on the component rather than providing it once and only once in the root module.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? I am injecting the service in the constructor of my root component and other components that are interested in the value changes. I thought you could only ever have one instance of a service, but from what you are saying that's clearly not the case. Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/providers

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet , I am using the `providedIn: 'root'` option in all my services, I am using the CLI, so this gets added for me automatically so this cant be a case of having multiple instances of the same service